# backword-sentence and forward-sentence are moving over paragraphs

Tags: motion, markdown, sentences

I use [markdown-mode](http://jblevins.org/projects/markdown-mode/) to edit markdown, but it's missing one very useful feature. Whenever I press `M-a` (`backward-sentence`) or `M-e` (`forward-sentence`) it takes me to the start or end of the paragraph, respectively. I want it to send me to start/end of the sentence (to the nearest period, question mark, etc).

Is there way to get markdown-mode to properly go to the start or end of the sentence?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're probably using single space sentences, which is fine, but you need to tell Emacs about it.

```
(setq sentence-end-double-space nil)
```