# Being inside a paragraph, how to move to the end of a sentence in Emacs?

Tags: motion, sentences

I know how to move to the end of a line, the paragraph, the s-expression, the word, or even the buffer.

But, I do not know how to move to the end of a sentence. Is there some way to move the end of a sentence? Maybe some package or tailor-made command for that?

I suppose it would be necessary to search for the closest punctuation inside the paragraph, such as `.`, `!` or `?`.

It could be the same position as the end of the paragraph, but not necessarily the coincidence would happen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [backword-sentence and forward-sentence are moving over paragraphs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2279/backword-sentence-and-forward-sentence-are-moving-over-paragraphs) You say that your other post solves the problem you ask about here. And your other post is a duplicate. So I think this question is also essentially a duplicate.

Comment: Well, it is a complicated situation. I was unaware of the command. Then, I realized the command was not working. The root of the problem is that I was trying to move to the end of a phrase (sentence). But, I trust on you @Drew. Whatever you feel like it is the best for our community! Since I have been asking a lot about Emacs in the last year or so, thanks a lot for the help provided and keep the good work! :)

Comment: More votes to close are needed than just mine. And I might well be misjudging. You might be able to tell better than I - you can just delete questions you pose, if you feel that they duplicate existing questions. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can navigate by sentences.

> <kbd>M-a</kbd>
> Move back to the beginning of the sentence (`backward-sentence`).
> <kbd>M-e</kbd>
> Move forward to the end of the sentence (`forward-sentence`).

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs)Sentences` for full details.

Take particular note of this:

> The sentence commands assume that you follow the American typist’s
> convention of putting two spaces at the end of a sentence.  That is, a
> sentence ends wherever there is a `.`, `?` or `!` followed by the end of
> a line or two spaces, with any number of `)`, `]`, `'`, or `"`
> characters allowed in between.  A sentence also begins or ends wherever
> a paragraph begins or ends.  It is useful to follow this convention,
> because it allows the Emacs sentence commands to distinguish between
> periods that end a sentence and periods that indicate abbreviations.
>
> If you want to use just one space between sentences, you can set the
> variable `sentence-end-double-space` to `nil` to make the sentence
> commands stop for single spaces.  However, this has a drawback: there is
> no way to distinguish between periods that end sentences and those that
> indicate abbreviations.  For convenient and reliable editing, we
> therefore recommend you follow the two-space convention.

Comment: thanks! Not sure if something is broken in my config though. It does not seem to work as expected.

Comment: Here, the problem is understood and solved: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/71972/why-is-forward-sentence-moving-the-cursor-to-the-end-of-the-paragraph-and-not-wo/71973#71973

Comment: Was it *really* not expected?  Your new problem/question was resolved by the specific thing that I had pointed out to you here with the prefix "**Take particular note of this**".

Comment: You are correct. But, the first time I read your reply, I did not fully understand the sentence-end-double-space point. Sorry for misunderstanding your thorough reply.